# how to access neo4j apoc uuid as a string?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to use apoc.create.uuid() in nodejs for the first time. In the neo4j browser I can see that the result is a string like this:

```
"a1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"
```

...but in node it appears as:

```
"\ta1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"
```

this is the cypher query:

```
MATCH (r:Race {race_id: $race_id})
WITH r 
MATCH (m:Member)-[v:HAS_VOTED]->(b)-[vr:FOR_RACE]->(r)
RETURN {votes:v.voter_choice}
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(result.records[0])) produces:
`[[{"votes":"\ta1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"},{"votes":"\ta1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"},{"votes":"\ta1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"},{"votes":"\ta1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"},{"votes":"bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"},{"votes":"bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"},{"votes":"bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"},{"votes":"bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"},{"votes":"bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"}]]`.

This is also not consistent across all return values...not all has this extra 2 leading characters. I am really not sure what causes this but I need these values to be consistent for comparison purposes.
Can anyone explain what is going on here?

EDIT: DB data:
m.member_id v.voter_choice  b.box_id
"a1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"  "   a1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"   "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"
"bbdbdff7-a178-479c-9dc7-894642365ca9"  "   a1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"   "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"
"57f81764-9a1e-4c02-bdd7-875e5e741471"  "   a1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"   "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"
"6417c1f8-646d-49e1-9ec3-e105f33637ae"  "   a1d0d202-b585-4130-ba96-4c75ca4860ca"   "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"
"bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"  "bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"  "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"
"7417f023-b1a9-4535-93a3-7a001305ccb7"  "bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"  "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"
"a0ea2113-63d8-4cde-a4e8-1ab20e3637f9"  "bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"  "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"
"ac913fcc-8070-4738-8946-c32ab7531446"  "bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"  "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"
"66514ccf-8808-4649-88b3-42f9db26616f"  "bd607ccd-85be-4b78-9d6e-89cbbb087d01"  "009d5129-a62c-49d7-aa4c-5ec9a8b01720"

I think I may have found the answer......in posting the edit above I noticed that the errant string has a leading space. I think this is the cause of the leading '\ta.....' let me know if you agree.

Comment: Would you maybe have some code to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @GuillaumeHanique ....I am not sure what you mean by "some code". The code in the question is what produce the behavior....please explain.

Comment: You are somehow running "JSON.stringify". What is the code that I could run that reproduces on my computer what you posted in this topic?

Comment: I have to to run stringify to see the output.....this i do all the time for debugging purposes....I will edit the question to include the db content

Comment: @GuillaumeHanique sometimes just communication will generate answers..since you keep asking for code I can only assume you don't realize that the code is neo4j cypher query code....but your questions still led me to the answer...so for those who might inadvertently come across this issue...the problem exists in neo4j browser...if you cut the uuid value from the side window and paste it in the query window a leading space is added to the uuid string...not sure why....so just  delete  the leading space(s) before running the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem exists in neo4j browser...if you cut the uuid value from the side window and paste it in the query window a leading space is added to the uuid string...not sure why....so just delete the leading space(s) before running the query.